# ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

Js code

```
if ($language == 'english') {
  var displayvalue = "";
  if (data[i].report_name.length >= 20) {
    displayvalue = data[i].report_name.substr(0, 20) + "...";
  } else {
    displayvalue = data[i].report_name
  }
  subMDesign += '<a  href=""  ng-click="getIndividualGraph(' + data[i].report_id + ',' + data[i].report_type + ')" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData(text, drag.action?reportId=' + data[i].report_id + '&reportType=' + data[i].report_type + '_' + data[i].report_id + '_' + data[i].report_type + '_22)"><span class="iconsweet">r</span><span class="tooltips" title="' + data[i].report_description + '" unselectable="on">' + displayvalue + '</span></a>';

} else {
  var displayvalue = "";
  if (data[i].report_name.length >= 20) {
    displayvalue = data[i].report_name_ar.substr(0, 20) + "...";
  } else {
    displayvalue = data[i].report_name_ar;
  }
  subMDesign += '<a  href=""  ng-click="getIndividualGraph(' + data[i].report_id + ',' + data[i].report_type + ')" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData(text, drag.action?reportId=' + data[i].report_id + '&reportType=' + data[i].report_type + '_' + data[i].report_id + '_' + data[i].report_type + '_22)"><span class="iconsweet">r</span><span class="tooltips" title="' + data[i].report_description + '" unselectable="on">' + displayvalue + '</span></a>';
}
}
var temp = $compile(subMDesign)($scope);
$("#reportUl" + $catid).html(temp);
```

I'm dynamically appending `subMDesign` to a `div` in last line. In the console, `subMDesign` is displayed as follows:

[image]

On drag start, an error displayed in console as follows:

> ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
>   event.dataTransfer.setData(text, drag.action?reportId=93&reportType=6_93_6_22)

and arrow mark pointed to reportId=93. Please help me solve this.

Comment: What?? You know the exact position, and the error message is clear. What kind of help you need here?

Comment: but i dont know what is the problem at that position

Comment: `drag.action?reportId=93&reportType=6_93_6_22` in pure JS does what? It looks like a part of an URL, but in your code it actually is an assignment.

Comment: assigning values to reportId and reportType and goto drag.action

Comment: When entered to the addressbar, yes, but not in JS. JavaScript has not url datatype.

Answer (score 0):

It's breaking because you're assigning a string without indicating it as such; e.g., you want to render this on the page:

```
// Note the quotes, to escape the string:
event.dataTransfer.setData(text, 'drag.action?reportId=93&reportType=6_93_6_22')
```

To achieve that, here's a simple refactor that also makes your code easier to read by removing duplication. I noticed that the only thing different between english/non-english is the report name field:

```
var displayvalue = "";
var field = ($language == 'english') ? 'report_name' : 'report_name_ar';

if (data[i].report_name.length >= 20) {
  displayvalue = data[i][field].substr(0, 20) + "...";
} else {
  displayvalue = data[i][field];
}

subMDesign += '<a  href=""  ng-click="getIndividualGraph(' + data[i].report_id + ',' + data[i].report_type + ')" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData(text, \'drag.action?reportId=' + data[i].report_id + '&reportType=' + data[i].report_type + '_' + data[i].report_id + '_' + data[i].report_type + '_22\')"><span class="iconsweet">r</span><span class="tooltips" title="' + data[i].report_description + '" unselectable="on">' + displayvalue + '</span></a>';

var temp = $compile(subMDesign)($scope);
$("#reportUl" + $catid).html(temp);
```

You'll see that I add **escaped** quotes (like this: `\'`) to prevent them from terminating the real string, but causing the quote to be rendered on the page.

For example:

```
var foo = "foo"; 
console.log(foo); // prints: foo
var bar = "\"bar\""; // we have to escape double quotes inside double quotes
console.log(bar); // prints: "bar"
var blee = "'blee'"; // no need to escape single quotes inside double quotes
console.log(blee); // prints: 'blee'
var blar = '\'blar\''; // but we have to escape single quotes inside single quotes
console.log(blee); // prints: 'blar'
```